# Lakeformation - Cross account access

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lake-formation

I have both Account A and Account B in this context. In Account A, I successfully registered a bucket using Lake Formation and it has 2 folders(which will be created 2 tables), executed the Glue crawler, and generated two tables as a result. Moreover, I effectively shared either the database or a specific table (to be precise, just one table) with Account B. This sharing was facilitated by Lake Formation, originating from Account A. As a result, Account B gained the capability to seamlessly run Athena queries, specifically focusing on that particular table. This achievement was reinforced by the establishment of a resource link associated with the database. This operational procedure has been executed without any issues.

The current configuration is functioning effectively. However, I'm interested in leveraging Lake Formation in alternative scenarios. To elaborate, consider the following scenario involving Account A and Account B: In Account A, I registered a bucket within Lake Formation and proceeded to share the corresponding data location with Account B. Notably, I intend for the Glue crawler to operate exclusively within Account B.

A challenge that arises pertains to the sharing mechanism. Presently, I'm only able to share the data location associated with the entire bucket, which inadvertently encompasses all its folders. This approach, however, contradicts my desired objective. I'm seeking a solution that enables me to share data locations based on specific folders, rather than granting access to the entire bucket. My inquiry is whether it's possible to achieve this fine-grained sharing based on folders, or if there exists an alternative method to accomplish this goal. Your insights and guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.